# Updating a filtered multi-row Vuex backed form results in "do not mutate vuex store state"

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

I have a multi row form in Nuxt/Vuex that I am successfully CRUDing rows. I can create, updated, and delete rows. Sandbox here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/multirow-fields-hkzql

I have another form where I am filtering the rows based on a value in the row. I can create and delete rows but not update them. Sandbox here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-filtered-multirow-fields-24cxb

When I edit a field in the filtered table I get the *[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers* error.

```js
// store/Table.js snippet
export const getters = {
  getField,
  filteredRows: state => {
    return state.rows.filter(row => row.key > 1);
  }
};
```

```
<!-- component/MultiRow.vue snippet -->
<tr v-for="row in filteredRows" :key="row.key">
  <td>
    <input v-model="row.key">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input v-model="row.value">
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="btn" @click="removeRow(row)">Remove row</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Is there a solution in `vuex-map-fields`? Is there a solution without it?

Comment: can you share your "removeRow" method?

Comment: Delete is working well in both scenarios. See the code sandbox links.

Answer (score 1):

Your are using Vuex in strict mode, so you cannot update the property of an object from the state outside a mutation, as explained here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html

To solve your issue, firstcreate a new mutation method:

```js
  updateRow(state, row) {
    const index = state.rows.findIndex(i => i.key === row.key);
    if (index > -1) {
      state.rows[index] = row;
    }
  }
```

Then replace your `v-model` by a `:value` + `@input`in order to update the "row" value with this new mutation method:

```
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="row in filteredRows" :key="row.key">
        <td>
          <input :value="row.key" @input="updateRow(row)">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input :value="row.key" @input="updateRow(row)">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn" @click="removeRow(row)">Remove row</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

And update your method list:

```js
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations("Table", ["addRow", "removeRow", "updateRow"])
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this. 
I made a copy of the sandbox to try it out.
https://codesandbox.io/s/filtered-multirow-fields-solution-1-je6gn
Unfortunately I didn't have any success. Following your method I see the event is triggered by the current state of the form isn't passed in so the state doesn't actually update. You can see this by pressing add at which time the updated field reverts.

I did get something going with passing in the value of the field from the $event. You can see this in the sandbox too.

I notice modifying the key is a Bad Idea so I've disabled that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Nicolas Pennec . I'm going to leave this open as, although it's somewhat resolved, I'd like to see if someone has an on campus `vuex-map-fields` solution that is less wordy and easier to maintain.